# Checkbox in Luminus

Tags: clojure, luminus

I started to learn Clojure this week, specifically I'm learning web development with Luminus. Since I want to understand the CRUD process, I setup a function to save my post into the DB:

```
(defn save-post! [{:keys [params]}]
  (if-let [errors (validate-post params)]
    (-> (response/found "/posts")
      (assoc :flash (assoc params :errors errors)))
  (do
    (db/save-post!
      (assoc params :created_at (java.util.Date.)))
    (response/found "/posts"))))
```

The query is pretty basic:

```
-- :name save-post! :! :n
-- :doc creates a new post record
 INSERT INTO posts
 (title, body, active, created_at)
 VALUES (:title, :body, :active, :created_at)
```

but the HTML form has a checkbox field:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="active" value="1">Published<br />
```

and when it is not selected, the field is not send and the SQL insert query sends the error message "No active field". How can I check if the element "active" is set and add it to "params" as true or false?

Something like:

```
  (assoc params :active (if (nil? params/active) false true))
```

after the ":created_at (java.util.Date.)" line.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I check if the element "active" is set and add it to "params" as true or false?

Looks like your code isn't far from working. You'll need to check the `params` map to see if it has the checkbox's value. If `(:active params)` is equal to `"1"` when the checkbox is checked, then you might do something like this:

```
(assoc params :active (= "1" (:active params)))
```

But what this is really trying to do is *update* a particular value in the map, which can be done more idiomatically:

```
(update params :active #(= "1" %))
```

Where the final argument is a function that takes any current value of the keyword and returns the new value.

Another potential gotcha: you may not want to use the `params` map as *direct* input to your DB query, because it could very easily contain keys/values that you don't want or expect. It'd be safer to pull only the values you need from it explicitly e.g. `(select-keys params [:title :body :active])`.

```
(def params {:active "1", :admin true}) ;; wouldn't want admin to leak through!
(-> params
    (select-keys [:title :body :active])
    (assoc :created_at (java.util.Date.))
    (update :active #(= "1" %)))
;;=> {:active true, :created_at #inst "2017-10-09T20:16:06.167-00:00"}
```